# How to make a tuple with components belonging to a type class an instance

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

I have the following problem: I defined a type class and want to declare tuples of types of this class to be instances as well. But I don't know how to get GHC to accept this declaration. Here a very simple example:

```
class Test a where
    elm :: a
```

And know for tuples I want to do something like

```
instance (Test a, Test b) => Test (a,b) where
    elm = (elm, elm) :: (a,b)
```

(Actually, I want to do something similar for more fancy type classes corresponding to vector spaces.)

How can this been done? Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Delete `:: (a, b)`.

Comment: Thanks! It works! I though a had been trying it first without the type annotation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
instance (Test a, Test b) => Test (a,b) where
    elm = (elm, elm)
```

This should work. The issue with you code, is that the `:: (a,b)` type annotation that you added is actually confusing GHC instead of helping it. The problem is that when GHC sees `a` and `b` it thinks that they represent some arbitrary types. But you don't want them to be arbitrary, you want them to be exact same types referenced in the above line. But GHC doesn't know that. If you leave the type annotation out, GHC will figure the correct types itself. Alternatively, you can change GHC's behavior by enabling the `ScopedTypeVariables` language extension, by adding the following at the top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

This will tell GHC that whenever there is a `class` definition, the type variables referenced at the top line, will be in scope for the rest of the definition. I am one of those people who think that `ScopedTypeVariables` should have been on by default but unfortunately this is not the case, mostly for historical & compatibility reasons. In fact, this question provides a good argument why `ScopedTypeVariables` being off by default is counterintuitive.

Comment: Thanks! It works! I though a had been trying it first without the type annotation...